# Is there a more efficient way to write this code

Tags: c#

I think the title says it all,

here's the code :)

```
private void listBoxComponents_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
        object item = listBoxComponents.SelectedItem;
        string name = listBoxComponents.GetItemText(item);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < terrains.Count; i++)
            {
                if (terrains[i].name == name)
                    terrains[i].EnableBoundingBox(true);
                else
                    terrains[i].EnableBoundingBox(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have allot of code throughout that is quite similar to this and I'm just hoping theirs a neater, quicker way to do acoomplish the same thing. Maybe with LINQ?

Thanks :).

Comment: what is the datatype of `terrains` ? is it Enumerable ?

Comment: It's a generic list

Comment: @tdkr80 consider posting this question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

You have not stated what exactly you mean by "more efficient", so I will just take the liberty to interpret this as "easier to read and type":

You can replace your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < terrains.Count; i++)
{
    if (terrains[i].name == name)
        terrains[i].EnableBoundingBox(true);
    else
        terrains[i].EnableBoundingBox(false);
}
```

With this one:

```
foreach (var terrain in terrains)
{
    terrain.EnableBoundingBox(terrain.name == name);
}
```

Note that in general, `foreach` loops are probably slightly *less* efficient at runtime than `for` loops. But the difference is probably tiny and absolutely nothing to worry about except in the more extreme real-time / high-performance scenarios. On the positive side, you end up with much simpler source code.

By the way, it might be better to compare strings using the [`string.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) method, because that makes it more explicit which culture and case sensitivity should be used for the comparison.

As another aside, you have mentioned LINQ. LINQ would be a bad fit here; let me briefly explain why: It is in theory possible to write a custom LINQ operator `ForEach`, which would accept an `Action<T>` delegate. It could be implemented as a `foreach` loop that invokes the delegate for each item in the source sequence. You could then write the following one-liner:

```
terrains.ForEach(terrain => terrain.EnableBoundingBox(terrain.name == name));
```

In my opinion, a plain `foreach` loop is actually more easily readable, even though it takes up more lines of code. But most important, remember what LINQ stands for: "Language-Integrated Query". LINQ expressions should *query* data, not *modify* it (i.e. have side effects). A `ForEach` custom operator, however, would be all about side effects; that's why it does not fit the LINQ paradigm and is not included in the Framework.

(As a final remark, my answer is basically a code review. If this is what you desired, perhaps the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site might have been the more appropriate place to post your question.)

Comment: This is probably even more efficient from a low level performance perspective, as it doesn't contain branches. However, the code behind `EnableBoundingBox` is likely to dominate runtime anyway :D

Comment: name is a string, and EnableBoundingBox takes a bool. I don't think this would work

Comment: @tdkr80: comparing strings with `==` or `string.Equals` will yield a `bool`,  of course this works.

Comment: @stefan Would this not be also optimized like this by the compiler?

Comment: @Maarten it's possible, but certainly not guaranteed. The `if (booleanExpression) return true; else return false;` style is so common that probably some compiler vendor implemented it...

Answer (score 3):

Your question may better qualify for codereview SO site as it works, but you want to optimize it.

I suggest you look into another datastructure for `terrains`. Using it as an array is not very efficient. If you create a dictionary on the `name` property, you will avoid the constant iterations for a certain named terrain.

UPDATE: As my initial suggestion is flawed, I come up with another.

I keep the idea to change the datastructure. You should make a `TerrainList`, that exposes in your example the functionality for the bounding box enabling and thus avoids to spread the terrain handling code all over your application.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        terrains.highlight(name);
    }
```

The implementation of the `highlight` function can then be optimized without sideeffects to other parts of your code.

Comment: I agree on your point that id would better fit to Codereview.
In his comment, he said that its a generic list, not an array.

Comment: Why would a dictionary work better here? There is still the setting to `false` for all other-than-name-is-equal cases.

Comment: @Maarten You are actually right, I obviously stopped reading at the `for`-loop. I will rephrase the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The code itself is fine.  LINQ isn't necessarily more efficient, despite sometimes having lesser code characters (if anything, it carries additional overhead, but that's usually stripped out during IL compilation, and I tend to find much LINQ to be less readable than the traditional blocks/loops).

If you use LINQ, it ends up compiling down to something similar to what you've written anyway, so really it's just syntatic sugar/code-candy.

The code is readable and you're not wasting resources inside a loop... what else do you want?

However, I personally would break that UI logic out of the event handler into it's own method.